Serre functor with infinite $Hom$
I am reading Furier-Mukai transforms in Algebraic Geometry and I try to understand basics properties of Serre functors.
Recall that for a $k$-linear category $C$, a Serre functor $S : C \rightarrow C$ is a $k$-linear equivalence with natural isomorphisms
$$ Hom(A,B) \simeq Hom(B,S(A))^*. $$
The author usually assumes this spaces to be of finite dimension to identify them with their bidual.
However I think this is automatic if we have a Serre functor. Indeed we have
$$ Hom(A,B) \simeq Hom(B,S(A))^* $$
but the same property for $(B,S(A))$ gives
$$ Hom(B,S(A)) \simeq Hom(S(A),S(B))^*.$$
So
$$ Hom(A,B) \simeq Hom(S(A),S(B))^{**}.$$
And finally, as $S$ is an equivalence, we have $Hom(A,B)\simeq Hom(S(A),S(B))$, so
$$ Hom(A,B) \simeq Hom(A,B)^{**}.$$
Is my argument wrong ? Do you see any mistake or know a category with Serre functor and infinite dimension $Hom$ spaces ?

This looks quite convincing. However, without further arguments this only shows that $X=Hom(A,B)$ is isomorphic to the bidual but not yet that the caninical embedding $i:X\to X^{**}$, $x\mapsto \delta_x$ (the evaluation of elements of $X^*$ in $x$) is an isomorphism. This reminds me of the James space $X$ which is a non-reflexive Banach space which nevertheless is isomorphic to its bidual.

@Jochen You are right. My isomorphism is functorial as I use only functorial morphisms, but maybe we need more precisely the evaluation one to be an isomorphism. I am going to check that in the proofs provided.

The proof looks correct (but as already discussed, this is probably not the preferred map). On the other hand, we can always rule out this case: If $\dim_k V$ is infinite, then $\dim_k V^* > \dim_k V$ if I remember correctly. (I think the functional analysis setup is different because one considers topological duals there.)
